# How to only trigger parent ng-click event for target child element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

Have a click event **ng-click="$ctrl.toggleSub(state)"** in the first row that is triggering the **ng-if="showSubCat"** event in the second row. This makes the second row appear when I click.

The problem is that it's causing all of the ng-repeat options to appear vs just the one I clicked.

For instance I'm getting:
Parent
    - Child
    - Child
Parent
- Child
- Child

I would like it to behave like this:
Parent
- Child
- Child
Parent

I only want the clicked ng-repeat options to expand accordingly. I've tried passing in the state object but am not having any luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```js
  toggleSub(state) {
    this.$log.log(state)
    this.$scope.showSubCat = !this.$scope.showSubCat
  }
```

```html
<tr md-row ng-repeat-start="state in country.states | orderBy: query.order">
        <td md-cell><a ng-click="$ctrl.toggleSub(state)">{{state.name}}</a></td>
        <td md-cell>-</td>
        <td md-cell>{{state.totalCount}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr md-row ng-repeat-end
                 ng-repeat="subcat in state.data | orderBy: 'subcategory'"
                 ng-if="showSubCat">
        <td md-cell></td>
        <td md-cell>{{subcat.subcategory}}</td>
        <td md-cell>{{subcat.count}}</td>
        <td md-cell>{{subcat.percentage}}</td>
      </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the `showSubCat` boolean a property of the `state` iteration object:

```
  toggleSub(state) {
    this.$log.log(state)
    //this.$scope.showSubCat = !this.$scope.showSubCat
    state.showSubCat = ! state.showSubCat;
  }
```

```
<tr md-row ng-repeat-start="state in country.states | orderBy: query.order">
        <td md-cell><a ng-click="$ctrl.toggleSub(state)">{{state.name}}</a></td>
        <td md-cell>-</td>
        <td md-cell>{{state.totalCount}}</td>
      </tr>
      <!-- BEFORE
      <tr md-row ng-repeat-end
                 ng-repeat="subcat in state.data | orderBy: 'subcategory'"
                 ng-if="showSubCat">
      -->
      <!-- AFTER -->
      <tr md-row ng-repeat-end
                 ng-repeat="subcat in state.data | orderBy: 'subcategory'"
                 ng-if="state.showSubCat">
      <!-- -->
        <td md-cell></td>
        <td md-cell>{{subcat.subcategory}}</td>
        <td md-cell>{{subcat.count}}</td>
        <td md-cell>{{subcat.percentage}}</td>
      </tr>
```

By making the `showSubCat` boolean part of the `state` iteration object, it will be different for each item in the parent `ng-repeat`.